# Why wouldn't Will tell the officer who pulled him over that he knew Detective Patterson?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, last-seen-alive

In the film [*Last Seen Alive* (2022)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10242388/), after Will's wife disappears, Will decides to take things into his own hands and kidnaps and ties up one of the people involved in his wife's disappearance.  He eventually gets pulled over for speeding, and in the process he tells the officer some untruths, which eventually leads to him being asked to pop his trunk.  At this point, he takes off.

Is there some rational reason for him to do this?  Did he think the Detective or the PD were involved somehow?  Or was he just going completely rogue and didn't want the PD to know anything about his actions?

Comment: He disobey detective orders so why should he mention him? What is your question?

Comment: @user7294900 - The question is, in my mind, if he had told the officer that he was in the area because his wife had disappeared, and then given the detective's name, he wouldn't have looked suspicious to the officer pulling him over.  The fact that he lied to the officer about what he was doing in the area confuses me.